# Sum of values in association list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have:

```
scaffold product name price:float
scaffold client name email
scaffold event title product_id user_id
```

event belongs to client and product. How can I show the `sum` of prices in client/show?

Clients_controller:

```
@events = @client.events
```

Client/show:

```
- @events.each do |event|
    = event.product.uprice
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Rails but try the [`.inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  What is `uprice` in your HAML?  What is relationship between `product`, `client` and `event` - may be you should share Active Record entity code?

Comment: *Mistake. not `uprice` but `price`. Event belongs to `client` & `product`. I see all events of client in client/show, but I want to count the total sum he must pay for all events :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `products` association in Client model

```
def Client
  has_many :events
  has_many :products, through: events
end
```

so you can,

```
@total_price = @client.products.sum(:price)
```

Read doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

Done! Thank you, Shin.

Solution:

1) in model
`has_many :products, through: :fiscal_periods`

2) in controller
`@total_price = @user.products.sum(:uprice)`

3) in show
`= @total_price`

Comment: Ok. plz choose answer :)